# shared model in backbone not acquiring events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Here is what i have as the backbone code:

```
myEventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var view_one = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        myEventModel.on('change:someChange',function(){alert('Change observed for view one')});
    }
    render: function(){ $('body').append('view one')}    
});

var view_two = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        myEventModel.on('change:someChange',function(){alert('Change observed for view two')})
    }
      render: function(){ $('body').append('view two')}
   });
```

So I have two views listening to a global model events. So when in console, I do

```
myEventModel.set({'someChange':new Date().getTime()});
```

i should see two alerts. But I don't.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ya4t1c24/)

Answer (score 0):

i've made some changes to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ya4t1c24/1/

you should create your model and views first, then events will fire.

```
myEventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var view_two = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        model.on('change:someChange',function(){alert('Change observed for view one')})
    }

});

var view_one = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        model.on('change:someChange',function(){alert('Change observed for view two')})
    }

});
var model = new myEventModel;
var var_view_one = new view_one({model: model})
var var_view_two = new view_two({model: model})
model.set({'someChange':new Date().getTime()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the definition of the views/models with creating objects of those types.

After you have defined your model, you should create an object of that type:

```
var myEventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var myEventModelInstance = new myEventModel();
```

Then in your views you want to listen to events fired from the object not from the model definition, so you should change your views as in:

```
var view_one = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        myEventModelInstance.on('change:someChange',function(){alert('Change observed for view one');})
    }
});
var view_two = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        myEventModelInstance.on('change:someChange',function(){alert('Change observed for view two');})
    }
});
```

Finally you need to create your view objects before changing the model object, as the view objects are the ones will react to the event, not the view definitions:

```
var viewOneInstance = new view_one();
var anotherViewOneInstance = new view_one();
var viewTwoInstance = new view_two();  
myEventModelInstance.set({'someChange':new Date().getTime()});
```

With the code above you will see 2 alerts with the message `'Change observed for view one'` because 2 `view_one` objects were created, and a single alert with the message `'Change observed for view two'` as a single `view_two` object was created.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48wz0wt4/1/)

Comment: it's better if you not use the word 'class' in your answer